# How to get type of class without initiating object?

Tags: vb.net, class, serialization

The consturctor of System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerial need the type of the class I want to serialize.

```
instance = New AnyClass()
Dim xmlszer As New XmlSerializer(instance.GetType)
```

No problem. But how can I get the type of AnyClass without initiating?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Try this:

```
Dim xmlszer As New XmlSerializer(GetType(AnyClass))
```

**[GetType Operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tay4kywk.aspx):**

> Returns a `Type` object for the specified type. The `Type` object provides information about the type such as its properties, methods, and events.

Answer (score 6):

Try this instead ;)

```
Dim xmlszer As New XmlSerializer(GetType(MyClass))
```